# What is the meaning of this RewriteRule and could it be simplified?

Tags: regular-expression, apache-httpd

```
RewriteRule ^he\/?(.*)$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

What is the meaning of this RewriteRule and could it be simplified?

I read it time and again and was lost each time anew.

It matches for `he/` but I just can't understand all the rest.

Answer (score 1):

###### Explanation

It matches a uri-path starting with `he` and an **optional** `/`, and captures the remainder of the uri-path (there's only one set of capturing parentheses, so it's captured as `$1)`.  Note that it will not capture any query strings if they are present.

It rewrites the rule as `https://example.com/$1`.

The `R=301` flags tells apache to use the permanent redirect code (301).  The `L` flag tells apache to stop processing any further rewrite rules for this uri-path.  i.e. if there are any more rules, they won't be applied even if they match the pattern.

In short, it redirects any URI starting with `he` on the local server to the same uri (without the `he/ or` he`` prefix) on `https://example.com/`, e.g. `he/foo.html` gets redirectred to `https://example.com/foo.html`

###### Simplification

Forward-slashes don't need to be escaped for either the pattern or the substitution in ModRewrite rules, so it could be simplified as:

```
RewriteRule ^he/?(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

BTW, if this is intended to redirect everything in the `he/` sub-directory of the document root, it will do that.  It will **also** capture any .html or other files in the document root that start with `he`, e.g. `hello.html` will be redirected to `https://example.com/llo.html`.

If you don't want it to do that then remove the `?` after the `/`.  In regex, `?` means match the preceding element zero-or-one times (i.e. matching it is optional).  If you want the `/` to be required for the pattern to match, then don't make it optional - use this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^he/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This won't, however, redirect the `he` directory itself if the uri doesn't end with `/`.  To do that, you'd need:

```
RewriteRule ^he($|/.*$) https://example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

IMO, the above rule is probably what you actually want....but if optional `/` IS what you want, then the `/?` isn't needed in the pattern - it will still match a URI with or without a `/` after `he`:

```
RewriteRule ^he(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

###### URI Problem?

Finally, I don't know how your apache server is set up, but I suspect that you should probably have a `/` before the `he` in the pattern, as URIs as seen by apache rewrite rules typically start with a `/`, e.g.:

```
RewriteRule ^/he($|/.*$) https://example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```